# Laravel - Merge multiple queries as one with each as a column

Tags: laravel

I have four different queries I want to combine as on queries, with each representing a column. Each stand for just only one row, because of the count(), sum() functions

I have written the queries

```
$lastsevendayssubscribers = DB::table('users')
                          ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total ') )
                          ->where(DB::raw("DATE(created_at)"), '>=', DB::raw('DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY'))
                          ->count();

        $activesubscriptions = DB::table('users')
                     ->where('plan_status', 1)
                     ->count();  

        $expiredsubscriptions = DB::table('users')
                     ->where('plan_status', 1)
                     ->count();  

            $currentDay = date('m');
            $currentdaybilling = DB::table("users")
                   ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
                   ->whereRaw('(created_at) = ?',$currentDay)
                   ->get();
```

I want the final result to look like this:

> |$lastsevendayssubscribers|$activesubscriptions|$expiredsubscriptions|$currentdaybilling|

Comment: Is there any reason you want to combine the queries? Why not just combine the results in an array?

Comment: I want to use foreach statement to bring everything together in a table. Also each have its own where clause and I dont know how to make them one. If there is any better way, you can guide me.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You mentionned a foreach, but since you are counting there is not really abetter way than making 4 separate, distinct requests in my opinion.

Comment: You could do selectSub() with closures to handle wheres to make a bunch of sub queries, makes for one messy query, just combine the results like the others say. much more readable. also, your active and expired subscriptions are the same plan_status = 1 on both, also, the lastsevvendays do will return 1 since you count the rows of a count

Comment: please can you give a sample

Comment: Why don't you just do `$result = [ $lastsevendayssubscribers, $activesubscriptions, $expiredsubscriptions, $currentdaybilling ];` is what I am asking?

Comment: How do I now call this on through foreach statement in order to display it on table <td>